# RegEx match string separated by space

Tags: php, regex

I've to validate a string pattern representing 2-2 letter language codes (see [*FacebookLocales.xml*](https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml)):

```
$languages = 'af_ZA ak_GH am_ET ar_AR as_IN ay_BO az_AZ be_BY';
```

So far I could come up with this:

```
preg_match ( "/^([a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}\s)+$/", $languages );
```

This works fine if there's a trailing space, if the trailing space is removed then it returns 0;

Comment: What about `ku_arab` or other non-2x2 codes?

Comment: I've id="ku_TR" name="Kurdish (Kurmanji)

Comment: Just make the space optional: `\s` -> `\s?`

Comment: You could always do `explode(" ",$languages)` and then check each individual entry.

Comment: WOW, this worked like charm :) thank you Rizier123

Comment: @surz: sorry but no, it's false. since it will match something like `en_USen_US`

Comment: thank you apokryfos for the alternative way

Comment: yeah, Casimir et Hippolyte is absolutely right

Comment: ... but you can add a word boundary before `\s?` or before the first letter in the group.

Comment: I can not use explode() and making the space optional is not the right solution, then what do you have next?

Comment: Just unroll it: [`'/^([a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2})(?:\s+\g<1>)*$/'`](https://regex101.com/r/lQ3tS2/1)

Comment: thank you Wiktor Stribiżew, this works !!!

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, to answer your first question, check this out [link](https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unroll your pattern like

```
'/^[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}(?:\s+[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2})*$/'
```

or - to shorten the pattern a bit:

```
'/^([a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2})(?:\s+\g<1>)*$/'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lQ3tS2/1)

The `\g<1>` recurses (repeats) the subpattern defined in the first capturing group (thus, it uses `[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}` rather than the captured value as opposed to `\1` backreference).